# Code to remove specfic elements from list doesn't work

Tags: python, list

I am trying to solve this codewars problem which involves an input of a list of directions, which include north, south, east and west. The problem consists of creating a function that eliminates the directions inputs that contradict themselves and return them in a list. For example, there is no point in going one unit south and then one unit back north.

I have been trying to solve this problem for a while and I have no idea why it doesn't work. If anyone could give me any help that would be great!

```
def dirReduc(arr):
    north = 0
    south = 0
    east = 0
    west = 0
    for i in arr:
        if i == "NORTH":
            north += 1
        if i == "SOUTH":
            south += 1
        if i == "EAST":
            east += 1
        if i == "WEST":
            west += 1
    while (north == 0 or south == 0) or (east == 0 or west == 0):
        if north != 0 and south != 0:
            arr.remove("NORTH")
            arr.remove("SOUTH")
            north -= 1
            south -= 1
        if west != 0 and east != 0:
            arr.remove("EAST")
            arr.remove("WEST")
            east -= 1
            west -= 1
    return arr
```

EDIT:
The actual problem is that the returned array at the end doesn't have the strings removed. It only returns the initial array.

For reference, the inputs tested will look something like this:

```
["NORTH", "SOUTH", "SOUTH", "EAST", "WEST", "NORTH", "WEST"]
```

Comment: Removing an element from a list won't get you a new list. It modifies it directly and doesn't return anything. So if you try to override your array with the return value of `remove` it'll just set the variable to `None`

Comment: @TedKleinBergman Makes sense. How should I then use remove (or another function) to remove a specific element from a list?

Comment: You just use it. It'll modify the list. But it doesn't return any value so you can't assign it to anything. Also, you shouldn't override your array with anything.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman I have changed it and still doesn't seem to be changing the list

Comment: Well, it depends on what you changed it to and what if you ever call it. Have you verified you're entering the if-statements?

Comment: @TedKleinBergman I just removed the "arr = " part of the line. I'm new to programming, I don't quite know what you mean by if I have verified if I'm entering the if-statements. The code is essentially the same as I posted on the post but without the "arr = "

Comment: Then it should work. Could be that your if-statements in the while-loop are never true. Or there is something else that's going on. Maybe the array is empty. Maybe it actually do remove it but you don't verify it correctly. This is pretty much the extent anyone can help you unless you [edit] your question with a [mre].

Comment: @TedKleinBergman: I think you must mean "*overwrite* your array" not "override" it.

Comment: @martineau I don't exactly know what it means, could you please explain it?

Comment: António: Generally speaking "overwrite" means "to write on top of" which in this situation means to replace the object the variable name was referring to with another. For example if `arr = [1, 2, 3]`, then `arr = arr.remove(2)` would result in `arr` being assigned the value `None` because that's what the sequence [`remove()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) method returns (i.e. nothing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider what this line means:

```
while (north == 0 or south == 0) or (east == 0 or west == 0):
```

While any of the directions equals 0, keep doing something, right? (The parentheses don't actually do anything here)

However, this example:

```
["NORTH", "SOUTH", "SOUTH", "EAST", "WEST", "NORTH", "WEST"]
```

It contains all directions, so none of those counts will be 0 and the loop never even runs once.

You probably meant:

```
while (north != 0 and south != 0) or (east != 0 and west != 0):
```

Or the equivalent:

```
while not ((north == 0 or south == 0) and (east == 0 or west == 0)):
```

But you could also just avoid a bunch of conditions with:

```
    while north != 0 and south != 0:
        arr.remove("NORTH")
        arr.remove("SOUTH")
        north -= 1
        south -= 1
    while west != 0 and east != 0:
        arr.remove("EAST")
        arr.remove("WEST")
        east -= 1
        west -= 1
```

Edit: you asked for clarification on why the loop never runs:

- you call the function with:
   `dirReduc(["NORTH", "SOUTH", "SOUTH", "EAST", "WEST", "NORTH", "WEST"])`
- so, `north == 2`, `south == 2`, `east == 1` and `west == 2`
- in other words, none of them are `0`
- your loop only runs if:
  `(north == 0 or south == 0) or (east == 0 or west == 0)`

Is that `True`, if the values are as stated above? No. So your loop doesn't run. Compare what happens if the condition is changed as I suggested.

Of course, the simpler solution is:

```
def dirReduc(arr):
    while 'NORTH' in arr and 'SOUTH' in arr:
        arr.remove('NORTH')
        arr.remove('SOUTH')
    while 'EAST' in arr and 'WEST' in arr:
        arr.remove('EAST')
        arr.remove('WEST')
    return arr
```

There's fancy ways to make the code even shorter, but that would hurt readability.

Comment: I don't exactly know why that is the case since I am iterating through every element of the list and, if a certain string comes up, I add 1 to one of the variables of the different directions, right?

Comment: @AntónioRebelo `while (north == 0 or south == 0) or (east == 0 or west == 0)` If the array contains at least one of each direction, then none of those conditions are true, and the code inside the loop will never execute.

Comment: You can do away with the pesky count variables altogether.  `while "NORTH" in arr and "SOUTH" in arr: arr.remove("NORTH"); arr.remove("SOUTH")`